# Analyze / Filter all variables without declaring each one?

Tags: java, filter, filtering

Say you have 70 separate int variables, and you wanted to analyze all of them and set any one which equals zero to 1, or another number.

Instead of writing 70 if else statements for each variable, can you write only one?

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
if("anyInt"==0){
"thatInt" = 1;}
```

?

(should mention I have no idea what a "collection" is)

Comment: you could put them in a collection and iterate over the collection and do whatever you like

Comment: An `int` can't be `null`.  Sorry to nitpick, but that's how primitives work.

Answer (score 1):

use an `int[]` Then iterate through them using a for loop

```
int[] nums = new int[70];
//put all your numbers in the array, i.e. nums[0] = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if(nums[i] == 0){
        //Do whatever to the number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need names for all of these values, put them in a Map (which is a collection):

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

myMap.put("varname1",1); 
myMap.put("varname2",0);
myMap.put("varname3",0);
myMap.put("varname4",2);

for (Map.Entry e : myMap.entrySet())
    if (e.getValue()==0) e.setValue(null);
```

You will need to import the collections (i.e. import java.util.*;).

The integer values are auto-boxed and unboxed between int and Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything else about your code, I would say that you should have the variables in an int array.

Then you would be able to loop through the array and only have one if statement.